# Forward declare a C++ class in an objective-C++ file?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I have an Objective-C++ file, and I have two classes: one Objective-C, one C++:

```
@implementation ClassA

....
// Create a copy of MyClass and use it in another C++ class
instanceOfCppClassB->callFunction(new MyClass);

@end

class MyClass : public AnotherClass
{
....

};
```

This compiles and runs fine with the C++ class up on top, but I'd like to move it to the bottom. When I move it to the bottom I get the error:

> Invalid use of incomplete type 'struct MyClass'
>   Forward declaration of 'struct MyClass'

Regardless of using typedef,struct,@class I get no love. How do I forward declare this class?

Comment: Can you show the use of MyClass in ClassA? `class MyClass` is how you pre-declare MyClass, but you might have to actually give its definition to use, for example, methods of that class in the implementation of ClassA.

Comment: I've updated the question with the usage for you, thanks, Jesse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declaration of a C++ class does not allow you to use instances of the class, you can just pass them around.  (To simplify the example, I have omitted any Objective-C.)

```
class Something;

void function(void)
{
    Something *x;         // Ok
    x = new Something();  // Error
    int z = x->field;     // Error
    x->method();          // Error
}

class Something : public Other { ... };

void function2(void)
{
    Something *x;         // Ok
    x = new Something();  // Ok
    int z = x->field;     // Ok
    x->method();          // Ok
}
```

You must put the entire definition of a class before you use it.  The forward declaration only allows you to declare variables using the class's type.

So the answer is: **what you ask is impossible.**  (What is wrong with putting the class definition at the top, anyway?)

You can still put methods at the bottom:

```
class Something {
public:
    void method();
};

@implementation ...
...
@end

void Something::method() { ... }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with putting the definition on top, but I didn't want to unless I had to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add class MyClass Prototype before ClassA.

```
class MyClass;
....
@implementation ClassA
....

// Create a copy of MyClass and use it in another C++ class
instanceOfCppClassB->callFunction(new MyClass);

@end
```

Comment: You cannot instantiate a class without a class definition.  (Try compiling the code, it will say, "invalid use of incomplete type".)

Comment: You still need prototypes for other methods, yes.

Comment: The problem here `class MyClass;` is a forward declaration.  It does not help, you might as well get rid of it.